# Cordova unable to install/uninstall any plugin

Tags: android, cordova

I noticed my Ionic 1 app crashes on Android 7, it seems a cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview known bug.

If I try to remove it:
`cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`

I get this error:

```
Uninstalling cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview from android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Removing "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview"
(node:6220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError
(node:6220) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

node:8.9.4
npm:5.1.0
cordova:8.0.0
ionic:3.19.1

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the platform then the plugin then re-adding the platform:

```
cordova platform rm android --nosave
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
rm -Rf plugins/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview node_modules/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
cordova platform add android --nosave
```

(the `rm` will wipe the plugin files if they are half-removed)